# Is it okay to lose the subject in formal writing?

Tags: subjects

In conversation we can talk like,

> Think you can do that?

Or,

> Hoped you might find it helpful!!

Here in the first sentence I excluded "You" and in the second sentence "I". I feel in both the sentences the meaning can be understood by the listener. Now is it okay to exclude those subjects in formal writing too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Formal written English is an artificial language governed by style manuals and the aesthetic and grammatical judgments of editors, peer reviewers, English teachers, and grammarians. It doesn't allow such frivolity as dropping subjects and verbs just because you, the writer, believe that the reader will understand what you're saying. The assumption of a writer of formal English has to be that readers are like computer-programming-language compilers: they're unable to understand what isn't written according to a particular set of rules. They can't figure out what is ambiguous. They don't want to be bothered making unnecessary inferences -- unless you're writing poetry, puzzles, or fiction.

**Your sentences are fine for informal written English, email, letters to friends and family, notes in your diary, but not for formal written English.**

When you have a listener, the listener can always interrupt your speaking and ask questions. When you're writing something, the reader and you are generally not in the same place at the same time. Therefore, you are obliged to make as certain as you can that your reader will understand everything you've written. So you have to write clearly enough to allow the reader to easily understand. Unless, of course, your goal is befuddle your reader with your prose.